# What happens if I register my entry?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, frequency, fourier, voice

Taking as an example that I want to record my voice. How does it appear in the frequency spectrum? Can I also view it on other spectra?

Comment: Hello Luca Leone and welcome to DSP SE. Your question is way too broad for someone to be able to answer it without having to cover a huge amount of Signal Processing topics. I suggest you divide your question down to more questions with a clear cut and concise problem.

Comment: I changed my question, I hope it will be clearer and with fewer arguments to lean on

Comment: You can "always" monitor your recorded data in the frequency domain. You can use the Discrete Fourier Transform (an implementation of the Fast Fourier Transform - FFT) to go from the time-domain to the frequency-domain.